# Desmarcar checkbox em cadeia

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma opção de checkbox que ao ser ativa, mostra um segundo check. Preciso garantir que o segundo checkbox só esteja ativo se o primeiro estiver. Minha função mostra e esconde o segundo check de acordo com o valor do primeiro, mas eu preciso que ela também desmarque o segundo quando o primeiro for desmarcado e isso não tá funcionando. Podem me ajudar ? Segue meu código.

```js
$("#ck1").click(function() {
  if ($("#ck1").is(':checked')) {
    $("#ck2").show();
  } else {
    if ($("#ck2").is(':checked')) {
      $("#ck2").prop('checked', false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck1" name="ck1" />
  <label for="ck1">Check 1</label>
</div>

<div style="display: none;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck2" name="ck2" />
  <label for="ck2">Check 2</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para esconder o segundo `checkbox`, você precisa esconder a `div` em que ele está:

```js
$("#ck1").on("change",function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') )
        $("#ck2").prop('checked',true).parent().show();
    else {
        $("#ck2").prop('checked',false).parent().hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck1" name="ck1" />
  <label for="ck1">Check 1</label>
</div>

<div style="display: none;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck2" name="ck2" />
  <label for="ck2">Check 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigada pela reposta. Esconder o segundo checkbox funciona, apenas desmarcá-lo com o `prop` que não acontece.

Comment: @goldenleticia Curiosamente só não funciona aqui. Aqui no meu PC funciona normal e no JSFiddle também: https://jsfiddle.net/vw3yqLh6/

Comment: @goldenleticia Deve ser algum bug no snippet do Stack.

Comment: mas no jsfiddle não está `prop`, está `attr`

Comment: @goldenleticia desculpe, esqueci de alterar: https://jsfiddle.net/vw3yqLh6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Suas condicoes estao erradas, pode ser algo como:

```
$("#ck1").change(function(){ // pega o evento de mudanca
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) // verifica se checkbox 1 esta marcado
        $("#ck2").show();
    else { // senao esconde e desmarca checkbox 2
        $("#ck2").prop('checked', false);
        $("#ck2").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, mas não fui eu que negativei sua resposta, ainda estou testando as soluções que me passaram.

Comment: Mudei o evento da função mas mesmo assim o `prop` não funciona...

Comment: Tem o evento e o else @goldenleticia

Answer (score 0):

Tem muitas maneiras de trabalhar com `jquery` fiz com classe diretamente no elemento, trabalhando na `div` você acabar esquecendo que o elemento ainda está setado, mas só não esquecer deste detalhe no momento da programação que tudo irá funcionar normalmente.

```js
$("#ck1").change(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $(".label-to").show();
        $("#ck2").prop('checked', false).show();
    }else {
    $(".label-to").hide();
        $("#ck2").prop('checked', false).hide();        
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck1" name="ck1" />
  <label for="ck1">Check 1</label>
</div>

<div >
  <input style="display: none;" class="label-to" type="checkbox" id="ck2" name="ck2" />
  <label style="display: none;" class="label-to" for="ck2">Check 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Minha resposta foi negativada, queria que me explicasse o motivo, caso tenha cometido algo errado na resposta, tento ajusta-la e aprender com isto, por isso estou começando a participar mais ativamente, aprendendo e tentando ensinar.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, mas não fui eu que negativei sua resposta, ainda estou testando as soluções que me passaram.

Comment: @goldenleticia questionei no geral para que a pessoa que negativou possa inserir um comentário assim posso corrigir o que está errado.